# Ansible conditional command not working on AWS server that runs ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ubuntu-20.04

I have a number of ansible scripts that execute commands on ubuntu servers on AWS.
One particular script needs to run both on ubuntu and on Amazon Linux instances.

I have a conditional command to skip some commands on Amazon Linux instances, which used to work fine until today, while I tried to run the script on a new server that I added that runs the new Ubuntu version (20.04 LTS).

This script and the conditional within it works fine for Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and Amazon Linux, but fails on Ubuntu 20.04.

This is the command that fails in my script:

```
- name: AMAZON LINUX Create jail local file
  file:
    path: /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
    state: touch
    mode: "u=rw,g=r,o=r"
  when: ansible_distribution == "Amazon"
```

and this is the error:

```
fatal: [MY_HOST]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_distribution == \"Amazon\"' failed. 
The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_distribution == \"Amazon\"): 'ansible_distribution' is undefined\n\n
The error appears to have been in 'MY_PATH/main.yml': line 27, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n
The offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: AMAZON LINUX Create jail local file\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I am wondering if this is a culprit on the new AMI that AWS has provided for new Ubuntu 20.04 - sounds like a reasonable explanation since the script works for other servers, but how could I overcome this?

Comment: Is also happening on local installs of *buntu 20.04.  Result for `ansible_distribution`.  Getting this result:  `hostname | SUCCESS => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false }`.

Comment: Looks like you need to upgrade ansible => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61460151/ansible-not-reporting-distribution-info-on-ubuntu-20-04